# Редирект на https

Tags: ssl, https

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Как эти параметры перевести на https?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавьте ещё одно перенаправление:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteCond %{HTTP:SSL} !=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://саййт.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```